# yield return vs Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I've learnt about lazy execution with yield return. Now I've seen a type which was introduced in .Net 4 (`Lazy<T>`). My question is: Is there any connection between these? I've checked the methods of `Lazy<T>` in ILSpy, but I haven't seen method implementation with yield return. So are they connected at lower levels?

Comment: [Both are monads](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/25/monads-part-two/) and have similar semantics. Oh, and theoretically each can be implemented in terms of the other, even though one direction would be very impractical …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they has nothing to do with each other .

`yield` is used to return current pointer to an object *during iteration*. It's very useful on iterating over large data sets and filtering/validating... some data contemporary (during iteration), so you don't need to cache filtered (say) values first, as it will make memory grow unreasonably big.

Lazy, is about a late/lazy or defered *initialization*, instead .  It's all about late intialization of an instance of a type you specify like such.

Example: you have a type, that on initilization allocates a lot of memory, but it's very common case in your application workflow that user will not need that type (some specific, user requested operation), so you use `Lazy<T>`, *to define* a type, but `do not initialize` it, so allocate memory only when it actually needed.

You can see that there is no any relation between these concepts.

Answer (score 7):

They have nothing to do with each-other.

Iterator methods (methods which use `yield return`, such as LINQ methods) used *deferred execution*.
That means that the code in the method will not run until you enumerate its results.

`Lazy<T>` is a wrapper that will only compute its value when the `Value` property is first accessed.

Comment: So both offer deferred value retrieval. That doesn’t sound like “nothing to do with each other”.

Comment: They aren't directly related is what he is saying. The yield is a bit more complex since it is primarily utilized in deferred execution. i.e. you may have a loop that calls an enumerable function that utilize the yield, which may short circuit and never fully unwind.  The Lazy<T> defers the whole value load in entirety, not partially.

Comment: Importantly, without further `Lazy`-like caching of the result, `yield return` will evaluate the "computation of its value" each time it is enumerated, where as `Lazy` WILL only evaluate once.

Answer (score 5):

No - an iterator is intended to serve a different function than `Lazy<T>`.

While iterators provide a way to implement `IEnumerable<T>` using deferred execution, and provide a form of "laziness", they're intended use case is quite different than `Lazy<T>`.  `Lazy<T>` provides lazy constructor *with multiple fetches of the same instance*.  Iterators, on the other hand, are intended to evaluate and return a *sequence of values*, not a single value.

Calling a method implemented with an iterator (`yield return`) will re-evaulate the sequence each time.

In addition, `Lazy<T>` can (optionally) provide thread safety guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  `yield return` is used to implement a method with a return type of `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerator<T>`.  As `Lazy<T>` has no  methods with such return types clearly iterator blocks aren't used in its implementation.

Answer (score 1):

No, the two doesn't use or depend on each other in any way.

Using `yield return` will not use `Lazy<T>`.

The point of `Lazy<T>` is to defer production of some costly data until (or even *if*) actually needed.

You can return it to say "if you really need this data, I can go and produce it, but if you don't need it, we've saved some time".